# Why Lord Shiva is in tapasya?

Tags: shiva, trinity, tapasya

Lord Shiva is said to be in 'tap' (तप) for Yugas, but Lord Shiva is one of the Trimurti gods and also the Mahadev, then why is he in tap?

. It is said that he prays lord brahma, and Lord brahma prays lord vishnu and Lord vishnu then lord shiva, thus completing the circle. (To ensure no one is supreme amongst the three). Is there some other reason behind this?

P.S. why do the Trinity gods do tapasya?

What is the goal behind their Tapasya ?

Comment: Your Q is little unclear.. 1. "Why Lord Shiva is in tapasya?" - all gods do tapsya.. do you want to say Lord Shiva is in deep meditation from Yugas now...or u mean to say he does tasya daily... 2. "he prays lord brahma" - from where did you read/hear/see this, any source?

Comment: PS: Shiva meditates/prays on Vishnu, Vishnu meditates/prays on Brahma and Brahma meditates/prays on Shiva. This is not to ensure supremacy but to complete the cycle life(Brahma), preservation(Vishnu) and death(Shiva).

Comment: Why do gods to tapasya is another question altogether. I think it is already asked on the site. By all gods, do you mean aforementioned gods (trinity)? Please check the site. Asking multiple questions in a post makes it too broad and your question will be put on hold. Please check if it is asked if not, ask it as a separate question. Please clarify the current question. It is unclear.

Comment: @Just_Do_It how is the circle of life is completed by the Trinity gods worshipping each other?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say the exact reason why they are doing tapasya. But while doing so, they are praying one another in a cycle.

I have read one short story about this in "Shiv Puran". It says,
Once, Mata Parvati got curious about the same thought that why is Lord Shiva always doing tap? To whom is he praying?
So he asked Lord Shiva the same. In reply to that Lord Shiva replied to her that he is praying to the almighty god Lord Vishnu.
And the same question was asked by the wives of the other Lords and after that, this fact was revealed that all the Trinity god are in deep meditation, praying to one another.

And they are not only praying to each other but also seeing the world in their meditation. As when anyone prays for them, they see them in their meditation and then pay them a visit to fulfil whatever they want.

So these two might be the combined reason for why are they always doing tapasya.